# Debugging Linux machine freezes

Tags: linux, debugging, freeze

I have 15 identical Linux RH 4.7 64-bit severs. They run cluster database (cluster is application level). On occasion (every month or so) a random box (never the same though) freezes.

I can ping the box and ping works. If I try to ssh in the box I get:

```
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

SSH is set up properly.

When I go to the server room, and try to login directly to console, I can switch consoles with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd>, I can enter a username, and characters do show, but after pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>, nothing happens. I waited 8 hours once and it didn't change.

I set up syslog to log everything to a remote host, and there is nothing in those logs. When I reboot the machine, it works without a problem. I have run HW tests - everything is ok, and nothing is in the logs. The machines are also monitored with NAGIOS, and there is no unusual load or activity prior to freeze.

I have run out of ideas; what else can I do or check?

Comment: What hardware tests did you run? What tools did you use?

Comment: HW is HP proliant, I used their util to check RAID status normal smart tools do not work, and I used memtest to check memory. I am having this problem for several months, and its never the same server.

Comment: What do RedHat support suggest?

Comment: Luka, at the console, does nothing happen after entering just the _username_ and hitting enter, or does it prompt you for the password and after _that_ not respond?

Comment: if you solved the problem, please edit your question to describe what was actually wrong and what you did for others to see.

Comment: Problem was never solved, but it went away after upgrading all Hosts to RH 5.3 and new version of Application  software.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like your kernel panicked in some way such that sshd couldn't send the server keys.  Possibly, the kernel was wedged in such a way that the network stack was still up, but the vfs layer was unavailable.

When I experienced similar problems on a RHEL4 system, I set up the [netdump and netconsole services](http://www.redhat.com/support/wpapers/redhat/netdump/), and a dedicated netdump and syslog server to catch the crash dumps and kernel panic information.  I also set the kernel.panic sysctl to 10.  That way, when a system panics, you get both the kernel trace and a copy of the memory on that system, to which you could analyse with the 'crash' utility.

You would certainly also benefit from setting up a serial console for the hosts, so you could see the console out put and potentially hit the magic sysrq keys.  Also, if you're willing to set up the networking and you have hardware that supports it, you can use IPMI to remotely poweroff,poweron,restart, and query the hardware.

(for what it's worth, RHEL5 has a similar functionality with kexec/kdump, only the crash dump is stored locally)

Comment: Hi, I have acces to console directly (via KVM), and there was nothing there. I could switch between virtual terminals type in my username, but that's it, also ctr+alt+del did not work, but should from console.

Comment: Also servers have HP's ILO, I can reboot them and see staus of HW from remote. There was no error there

Comment: Did you check the syslogs during that time?  It sounds like a panicked kernel.  I don't trust KVMs on my linux servers, too often the kernel panic doesn't show up on the console, or it's corrupted or just the last couple lines, that's why I prefer a serial console.

Comment: This does not sound like a kernel panic. Console switching still works and the login program is still active.

Comment: yes I had syslog redirected to central syslog server. There is nothing unusual in the logs.

Comment: the kernel can be wedged in such a way that you can switch consoles, but it's clear that the login process isn't active, otherwise it'd respond when the username was typed.  I think the only thing to do at this point would be to set up the netdump and initiate a crash dump, and analyse the crash dump.

Comment: "I can enter a username, and characters do show, but after pressing Enter, nothing happens." — login works, but you can't spawn an new process to get past that. That says "out of memory" to me.

Comment: Likewise, ssh is answering, but then can't spawn a shell. This is classic.

Comment: Well, I set up netdump, i have a screen with ssh connections to all 15 servers.

Comment: I also increesed nofiles resorce limit to 65500. Most other limits are set to unlimited. Are there any parameters in sysctl I should tweak?

Comment: @mattdm: I hate to belabour the point, but simply because the TTY is responding to keypresses doesn't mean that the login process is actually doing anything.  If it responded with a password prompt, perhaps it's operational, but that's not the case.  I agree that there could be a memory resource limitation, but I find that unlikely.  Typically, if memory is exhausted like that, you'd see plenty of OOM messages on the console and/or logs, and the OP hasn't reported anything unusual in the logs, although OOM could have killed syslogd.  Check the local logs too?

Answer (score 3):

I will bet dollars to donuts that you are running out of memory. The system is grinding to a halt as it tries to figure out where to get some from. It may be happening so quickly that your monitoring doesn't catch it. I'd step up monitoring, including remote logging of memory usage. Check in the logs for OOM messages as well.

(You may even just want to have some ssh windows open running top.)

Answer (score 3):

To me this sounds like the system is out of resources so the process needed by the server side of ssh cannot be allocated.

The actual bottleneck can vary - out of processes or out of memory - and the only way to be sure is to look at the logs and console to see if anything is present there.  You may want to set up a scenario of pre-started ssh-jobs - one to each machine - simply to be prepared next time it happens.

If it is *really* bad, then you may want to consider starting another shell with more built-in commands so you can investigate more without having to start an extra process as this may not be possible.  Also "tail -f /var/log/*" may be very useful.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The only time I've seen anything similar was where a KVM switch was used and a keyboard hot-key (e.g. alt+n) was used to switch between servers. It didn't happen every time and it was the server being switched away from that was affected - so it wasn't immediately noticeable. No lock-ups would occur if a physical button on the KVM switch itself was used to switch between servers. If the hot-key was often used, occasionally a server would not allow new logins. Existing SSH sessions were unaffected.